# InfluxDB: would each unique tag combination containing non-growing data cause cardinality issue?

Tags: time-series, influxdb, cardinality

Let's say I have InfluxDB (2.7) measurements with two tags `(id, site)` and arbitrary fields. The `id` is fixed, and when the device is deployed to a different location, the `site` tag would change, which means that the old combination of `(id, site=old_site)` will stop receiving any more data (query is still possible). So, each `site` tag would have non-overlapping segments of time-series.

If I understand correctly, each unique `(id, site)` combination causes increased cardinality. I wonder if there is optimization in influxDB to "ignore" thoses inactive series? Would my abovementioned high-cardinality issue be less or equally concerning as the normal high-cardinality issue (many active tag combinations)?